# TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting error when plotting my model.
My code is

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

Showing error

> 1 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py in
>   model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir,
>   expand_nested, dpi, subgraph)
>       167             node_key = layer.name + '_ib-' + str(i)
>       168             if node_key in model._network_nodes:
>   --> 169                 for inbound_layer in node.inbound_layers:
>       170                     inbound_layer_id = str(id(inbound_layer))
>       171                     if not expand_nested: **TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable**

My keras model summary is

```
    Model: "PneumoniaModel"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 84, 84, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2 (None, 90, 90, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv0 (Conv2D)               (None, 84, 84, 32)        1600      
_________________________________________________________________
bn0 (BatchNormalization)     (None, 84, 84, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 84, 84, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
pool0 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 42, 42, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 56448)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc (Dense)                   (None, 1)                 56449     
=================================================================
Total params: 58,177
Trainable params: 58,113
Non-trainable params: 64
```

Answer (score 2):

I had just solved it,

Error was in importing
instead of

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import  plot_model
```

I was importing

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
```

I was using tensorflow 2.0 in my model so it solved.